# How to do make CSS Toggle like this?

Tags: jquery, css, toggle

I am developing a site and on FAQs page i need to show this type of FAQs.
[image: reference]

When click on (Q) the (A) should open with jquery animation.
1 Question should be open at a time.

If click on other (Q) the previous should close and clicked will be opened.

```
<div class="faqBlock">

    <div class="qa">
        <dt>How do I buy Snoopra?</dt>
        <dd>Just decide whether you want to pay monthly or yearly, click on the buy now button, fill out the payment details and you’re done!</dd>
    </div><!-- qa -->

</div><!-- faqBlock -->
```

Comment: Please post code that you have tried.

Comment: I didn't added any code. Just thinking how it will be done also finding solutions for this. If you know please help me out so it works on every browser

Comment: Stackoverflow is for helping you, not doing your work for you. Please try to create something on your own, then we can help you if it doesn't work. There are many tutorials online for doing just what you need.

Comment: It sounds like an [accordion](https://www.google.com/#fp=99c5e0e35578f7fd&q=jquery+accordion) is what you're after..

Comment: Thanks.. doing the code work now.. will send here if it didnt work

Comment: @user1643546  : See http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ You can implement it easily as you access to the source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's called **accordion** and the easyest way to build it is:

```js
$('.qa h3').click(function(){
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.qa > *{margin:0; padding:8px 16px;} /* all */
.qa > h3{cursor:pointer; border-top: 1px solid #eee;} /* questions */
.qa > div{display:none;} /* Hide all answers */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qa">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
  <div>answer 1...</div>
  <h3>Question 2</h3>
  <div>answer 2...</div>
  <h3>Question 3</h3>
  <div>answer 3...</div>
</div>
```

### To close previously opened ones and toggle clicked one:

```js
$('.qa').each(function() {
  
  var $q = $(this).find("> h3"),
      $a = $(this).find("> div");

  $q.click(function() {
    var $qa = $(this).next(); // Get the question's answer
    $a.not($qa).slideUp();    // Close all answers (not the next's one)
    $qa.slideToggle();        // Toggle answer
  });

});
```

```css
.qa > *{margin:0; padding:8px 16px;} /* all */
.qa > h3{cursor:pointer; border-top: 1px solid #eee;} /* questions */
.qa > div{display:none;} /* Hide all answers */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="qa">
  <h3>Question 1</h3>
  <div>answer 1...</div>
  <h3>Question 2</h3>
  <div>answer 2...</div>
  <h3>Question 3</h3>
  <div>answer 3...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you didnot read "If click on other (Q) the previous should close and clicked will be opened." as one of the requirements in the question.

Comment: @RupamDatta ohh thanks, probably the Q was edited while I started to play around? dunno, in any case... edited. :)

Comment: Well the code is working fine.. but its a bit jerky.... When the (A) is open the height is getting disturbed.

Comment: @user1643546 not in my demo. Fix your CSS

Comment: The CSS padding is making the problem.. Trying to fix

Comment: well i have fixed the issue. thanks to all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Please find a solution to the problem you posted. I guess it works as per your requirement.

http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/ESLEB/1/

```
$(document).delegate('.q','click',function(){
    $('.a').hide();
    $(this).next('.a').show();
});
```

Comment: Remember that **show - hide** is a great example of **bad** User Interface (which leads to a really poor UX)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Good job done. By the way, I never know that **show - hide** is a great example of **bad** User Interface. Can you please explain the line with documents supporting your comment? I'd really want to know more on this.

Comment: [Docs: Why is fade good UX](http://jsbin.com/aNeMoLa/1/) --- [UX and show-hide_The next step to epilepsy](http://jsbin.com/aNeMoLa/2/)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not sure what your comment mean. I wanted a document supporting your comment above.

Comment: Posting a link to some document that talks about why a *motion* | *animation* is more user friendly, would be an insult to a common sense of perception and user interaction / expectation

Comment: A good UX/UI expert should also know how many ms (milliseconds) should some web/service/interaction-response be delayed (if faster than a user could perceive as a *natural* response), an animation last (to give the user the feeling that something happened, without confusing, surprising him) and many other finesses that are just product of expert observations toward a better UI :) (in short)

Comment: I'd disagree. An animation used for the sake of animation is, I feel, an extra to the user. I personally, being a user, would not want to see a delay when something straight forward is possible. Moreover a normal person can see the difference of the action (hide/show). I don't think a delay is required here. Well this is my take on hide-show.

Secondly you said **show - hide** is a great example of **bad** User Interface. I still not get a agreeable statement favouring your comment.

Comment: The comment regarding **delay** was related to a service as a server/app or action-request delay. This theme is in any case too wide and sensitive (but at the same time so intriguing and amazing) to be discussed here. It's almost like art, music, and involves also psychology. If one don't understand it, or have a sense for it, that's why there are UX/UI experts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36446/discussion-between-rupam-datta-and-roko-c-buljan)

Answer (score -1):

There is [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)  for you.Make use of it.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').slideToggle('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/jcnMa/23/)

Comment: can please make code for this according to the image

Comment: @user1643546 we can help you to give some hints,Or correction.We won't code for you :)

Comment: I have added the code for this. im using DD and DT for this purpose.

Comment: please tell me how this function will be done with slideDown fuctions. I have added above JS but its getting jerky

Comment: I guess you didnot read "If click on other (Q) the previous should close and clicked will be opened." as one of the requirements in the question.

Comment: @RupamDatta Can you please check the demo,I provided ? It's closing right? When you click on section one,Section two closes.Please cross check :)

Comment: Yes it is closing when it is opened. Ideally as per the question asked, only one answer should be opened at a time. Please read the problem statement once more.